# How to Finding USB port Address with dev/tty/usb.. format in raspberry pi 4 ver.b?

Tags: python, usb, raspberry-pi4

I had a problem for searching USB Address Port in Raspberry Pi. I'm using RIGOL DSE1102E Digital Oscilloscope, to acquiring data to my Raspberry Pi 4 Ver. b.

So, i'm connecting from Raspberry Pi 4 to my Oscilloscope USB Slave's port and i'm checking in my Raspberry terminal. So i'm typing

> pi@raspberrypi:~$ lsusb

so, it returned

```
Bus 002 Device 001 : ID 1d6b Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1ab1:0588 Rigol Technologies DS1000 SERIES
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

so i'm assumed my Raspberry is connected to my instrument because appearance of this line

> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1ab1:0588 Rigol Technologies DS1000 SERIES

so, based on this case how to know this

> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1ab1:0588 Rigol Technologies DS1000 SERIES

address in format

> dev/tty/usb...

because i want to code it using pyos library from Python

Comment: Your `dev/tty/usb...` thing is kind of vague.  Could you give an example of the *exact* string you are trying to get and be more specific about how you will use that string?  Have you tried running `ls /dev` and `ls /dev/serial/by-id` in a shell already to look around in your filesystem and see what is there?  Also, I can't find a library names `pyos`, can you link to it?

Comment: dev/tty/usb0 i mean, those "..." is a number like 0, 1 and etc as i understand. And Pyos one, i mean os library on python (import os)

Comment: in this case i just want to find my usb address who was connected to my osscilloscope. For add to the one of os.open( ) parameter.

Comment: Do you mean `/dev/ttyUSB0`?  It's important to be precise in computer programming.

Comment: yes. So how do i know its connected to my instrument or any USB addres was connect to my Instrument ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `/dev/ttyUSB0` I recommend using the symlinks provided by the kernel in `/dev/serial/by-id`.  They contain a lot of info about the USB device, including the vendor ID and product ID, so you can be sure you are opening the right device.  They also should be pretty stable, not depending on the USB port you use or the order the devices are plugged in.  Run `ls -l /dev/serial/by-id` to explore the options.

Comment: is it working when i use these /dev/serial/by-id to fill port in parameter on serial.Serial( ) at Pyserial library ?

Comment: Yes, because the if you run `ls -l /dev/serial/by-id` command I suggested you can see that the entries in that directory are actually symbolic links to things like `/dev/ttyUSB0`, so they work.  Also, you don't have to take my word for it, why not try it?

Comment: i was tried and it returned, usb-GOOD_WILL_INSTRUMENT_CO.__LTD._GDS-1102A-U_EN121083-if00

Comment: Ok, so what does that link to and did it work when you tried it?  Have I successfully answered your question?

Comment: If I've successfully answered your question, please click the checkmark to accept my answer.  If not, please let me know what the specific problem is.

Comment: it was checked, Thank you for your answer